# Postgresl json lists values extraction

Tags: json, postgresql

I have got following `jsonb` column in a table with example values:

```
{
    "persons": [
        {
            "person": [
                {"id": "1", "name": "John"}
            ]
        },         
        {
            "person": [
                {"id": "2", "name": "Oscar"}
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there a way to create a row value with `1-John, 2-Oscar`? Suppose that there is not fixed number of persons for each row.

I tried several functions and crossjoins but nothing worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have two nested arrays, you need to unnest them twice:

```
with data (doc) as (
values ('{
        "persons": 
        [
        {"person": [{"id": "1", "name": "John"}]},         
        {"person": [{"id": "2", "name": "Oscar"}]}
        ]}'::jsonb)
)
select t2.p ->> 'id' as id, 
       t2.p ->> 'name' as name
from data, 
     jsonb_array_elements(doc -> 'persons') as t1(p),
     jsonb_array_elements(t1.p -> 'person') as t2(p);
```

returns:

```
id | name 
---+------
1  | John 
2  | Oscar
```

To concatenate that into a single row, use `string_agg()`:

```
with (...) 
select string_agg(concat_ws('-', t2.p ->> 'id', t2.p ->> 'name'), ', ')
from ...
```

returns:

```
string_agg     
---------------
1-John, 2-Oscar
```

Comment: Yep, but desired output is one row: '1- John, 2-Oscar'. Any idea?